# Can two routers be in same IP-range?

Tags: networking, router

I'm having a modem with a built-in router, that connects to the internet through the 4g-network (productname: `Huawai`).

To this modem, I have a router connected in Lan1 (productname: `ZyXEL`). So my Huawai gets the internet and passes it on to my ZyXEL. I'm connected to the wireless-LAN on the ZyXEL. I'm using this setup, since the wireless-signal on the ZyXEL is stronger than on the Huawai (and the ZyXEL can't connect to the internet).

I have an IP-camera connected to the ZyXEL, that I would like to be able to access from an external IP-address. 
   I've Googled around, and it looks like, that I should do a port-forwarding to the given IP-address, in the router. I assume, that I have to do it in the Huawai-router, since that's the most-outer point of my network. However... I can access my Huawai-router by going to a browser and going to this IP:

```
192.168.1.1
```

But I can access my ZyXEL-router by going to a browser and going to this IP:

```
10.0.0.1
```

I can see that my own IP is 10.0.0.35 (which makes sense, since I'm connected to the ZyXEL-router.

So my questions are this:

1) Can I change the IP of the ZyXEL-router to be 192.168.1.2, so that the two routers are in the same IP-range? Or would that reck something?

2) Would it be better (and possible), if I just do a port-forward from my Huawai-router to the IP-cameras IP (which is 10.0.0.33, since that is connected to the ZyXEL). I mean, is that possible, since it's a different IP-range, or am I getting this all wrong?

3) Or am I trying to do something idiotic this way, by having two routers? Would it be better to simply throw the ZyXEL-router out, live with 2 bars instead of 4 and then set it all up with a single router?

4) And how do I know, which port it would be smart to do the forwarding from. I can find several articles on Google, that I should choose the port that I forward with caution - but I can find nothing about, which one(s) to choose?

Comment: This is asked so often :/

Comment: @grawity, indeed. the question is just complex enough that novices are never certian that their circumstances are the same as everyone elses, and want a specific validation. It does seem to happen most with survelliance 'afficionados' though. I wonder if theres a psych research paper in that?

Comment: Guys! I'm right here, and I can read your comments as well. You're hurting my feelings, you bullies, you!

Comment: Surpisingly enough, it does seem like most double-NAT questions are related to IP cameras. Don't worry about being new to advanced networking; we all started there once, and I'll admit, the more involved scenarios are intimidating, and without familliarity, its hard to tell whether the issue described by guyX's thread on configuring his bittorrent client is simmilar or the same as your issue with cameras. ;-)  Now, all that said, does my answer answer your question to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Can I change the IP of the ZyXEL-router to be 192.168.1.2, so that
>   the two routers are in the same IP-range? Or would that reck
>   something?

Depends on how they are connected. if they are both acting as routers, and the input of one is connected to the output of the other, then no, they cannot be in the same IP space. routers route between two differant networks. you may be able to tell the Zytel box that it is not a router, but a bridge/switch/AP, but as long as it is a router, and they are connected in serial as described, they the WAN and LAN IP networks must be differant, from every routers perspective.

> 2) Would it be better (and possible), if I just do a port-forward from
>   my Huawai-router to the IP-cameras IP (which is 10.0.0.33, since that
>   is connected to the ZyXEL). I mean, is that possible, since it's a
>   different IP-range, or am I getting this all wrong?

I haven't worked with ZyTel much, but as I understand your description, the 10.0.0.0/x network space is only internal to the zytel, which means that the haunwei box cannot see the 10.0.0.0 network directly. you would have to create port forward rules on the huanwei box, AND on the Zytel box to send traffic through both NATs.

> 3) Or am I trying to do something idiotic this way, by having two
>   routers? Would it be better to simply throw the ZyXEL-router out, live
>   with 2 bars instead of 4 and then set it all up with a single router?

having two routers is not idiodic if one of them is under ISP control, or you have an advanced network scenario (you don't appear to, but its worth noting), or you have a need to progressively firewall as traffic approaches your internal LAN (for instance you might have public webservers with looser rules than your LAN's). That said, it will complicate matters, in terms of port forwarding.

> 4) And how do I know, which port it would be smart to do the
>   forwarding from. I can find several articles on Google, that I should
>   choose the port that I forward with caution - but I can find nothing
>   about, which one(s) to choose?

For best practices, pick a port betweeen 2000 and 10000, that is unregistered on this list: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt
if you don't use a protocol on the list, it is usually safe to use that port for whatever purpose you like, but if its just as easy, you might as well pick an unregistered port to prevent any conflicts with other infrastructure hardware (like ISP level firewalls/CarrierNAT) that may make differant assumptions about traffic on that port.

Comment: Can the devices connected to ZyXEL have access to ISP's Huawai? Just to get to the Huawai's control panel easily - it is located in the Huawai's address space. Currently, I have to reconnect to Huawai network (wired or wireless) for that. Can static routing table help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can I change the IP of the ZyXEL-router to be 192.168.1.2, so that the two routers are in the same IP-range? Or would that reck something?

Of course. It's hard to imagine how you could build complex networks if you couldn't have two routers in the same IP range.

> 2) Would it be better (and possible), if I just do a port-forward from my Huawai-router to the IP-cameras IP (which is 10.0.0.33, since that is connected to the ZyXEL). I mean, is that possible, since it's a different IP-range, or am I getting this all wrong?

No, that's worse.

> 3) Or am I trying to do something idiotic this way, by having two routers? Would it be better to simply throw the ZyXEL-router out, live with 2 bars instead of 4 and then set it all up with a single router?

No, you can use both routers. Just use the ZyXEL router as an access point.

> 4) And how do I know, which port it would be smart to do the forwarding from. I can find several articles on Google, that I should choose the port that I forward with caution - but I can find nothing about, which one(s) to choose?

There's nothing to forward. Disable the DHCP server on the ZyXEL and connect the routers LAN-to-LAN.

Comment: On point one, note that it appears that the routers are connected serially, not in parallel. Zytel's WAN (Huanwei's LAN) cannot be the same network. from the Zytel boxes perspective, at least as long as its acting as a router.

Comment: @FrankThomas This is not true, I have a my ISP router on 192.168.1.1 (not in bridge mode but with DHCP turned off) and my personal router network mesh on 192.168.1.2, it all works perfectly

Comment: @Tofandel, The op has described a network with two routers connected serially (not in a parallel mesh as you have descrived). it is quite possible to have two routers with interfaces in a network, but the issue is that a router cannot route between two networks using the same IP range. the logic used in IP routing falls apart when a router has two adjacent interfaces on different physical networks that are using the same subnet. what would the routing rule to reach 192.168.0.x from the network 192.168.0.x look like? It would never send traffic to the gateway.

Comment: @FrankThomas It can be done and there are sometimes reasons to do it using techniques like proxy ARP. For example, say you want to have one network but with machines on that same network in two distinct physical locations. But it's almost certainly not what this question is about.